# Ajax GET request over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, ajax, https

How can I send an ajax **GET** request over **HTTPS**?

`$.get` throws this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://********. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Is there another way or some workaround to get this working?

If I navigate to the url with **Chrome** I'm able to get the response. I see no reason why it shouldn't work work over an ajax request.

Comment: It's looks like a cross-origin issue, not HTTPS. Whatever code you've used, you should provide that with some context on the URL in relation to the page/site it's running in.

Comment: Are you calling $.get with an object with your details as in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ or just by itself?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You cannot make an AJAX request to an `https` page if you are currently in `http` because of the [**Same Origin Policy**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

The **host**, **port** and **scheme** (protocol) must be the same in order for the AJAX request to work.

You can either make sure that the originating page is on the same host and scheme or implement [**CORS** (cross-origin resource sharing)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) on the target domain to permit this particular request.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery v. 3.3.1]

I have a web application, where all resources and traffic are via HTTPS.

Yet, I found that I can't send `$.ajax()` or any of the specific `$.get`, `$.post`, etc. due to (Chrome output):

Refused to connect to 'http://mywebapp/api/mycall' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self'".

It was due to the HTTPS page making the AJAX requests through HTTP and I found no way to force HTTPS.

What is crazy is what fixed it. Calling `$.get('/api/mycall/')` outputs the above error with "Refused to connect to 'http://mywebapp/api/mycall'", which omits the ending forward slash in the actual call in the code. So from the error it looks as if the forward slash wasn't there.

I have done multiple calls and every single one fails when there is an ending slash in the url being called. The same ones all succeed without one.

So calling `$.ajax({ url: '/api/mycall'})` works, whilst  `$.ajax({ url: '/api/mycall/'})` doesn't.