# Macro for a website

Tags: php, jquery

Is it possible to automate following steps seamlessly?

1) Login to a website

2) Click a tab/follow a link

3) Click another button

4) Paste some text in a textarea and click save button

For Example: Logging into stack overflow and posting a question automatically.

Comment: You want to make this steps done automatically ?

Comment: yes @SulthanAllaudeen

Comment: Is that your website and do you know the content inside that ?

Comment: Yes it is a CMS and I have logins.

Comment: So, Why can't you do [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job ? Do you want me to assist in it ?

Comment: Yes please. I am not much familiar with cron jobs.

Answer (score 0):

As it is your website, According your requirement you shall use [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job from your cpanel.

It will put the direct entries in the table that you wanted to save.

You should save the text that is to be stored in the table (i.e., content to be saved) inside the cron.php (or any name that you prefer)

and then form your cpanel you should set the time when the file should be executed

```
/home/username/public_html/cron/cron.php
```

Here is the rough syntax :

```
minute hour day month day-of-week command-line-to-execute
```

You can choose the time your file should be executed from cpanel itself.

Here is the [link](http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml) to learn more about cron job

Comment: Now I understand what you meant but this is not the case. For the better understanding of my question I put an example. I know how to run cron jobs in cpanel. What I am asking is how to code these steps in the cron.php

Comment: In the `cron.php ` you don't want to instruct to choose the menu or navigate to page or anything. You just need to have insert query in it.

Comment: Let me tell you I have limited access to the CMS. All I can login through browser to navigate to query bank to run queries.

Comment: I can understand the problem. Is there difference between `saving details to table` directly and putting entries from browser ?

Comment: Obviously there is. Let me know what makes you think like `saving details to table` directly. It might help me to improve my question. I tried php browser simpleTest but it failed to login possibly due to https or other security concerns.

Comment: You tried by ajax request method ? If so you can't do it over https as you can read it from here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15375957/3282633 I would recommend you to study and make the updates in all the tables that is equivalent to the direct entry